# How to Join & Groupby in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running the following command in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
SELECT 
  order.adate,
  details.ordid,
  sum(details.price) as total 
FROM details,order 
where details.ordid=order.ordid 
GROUP BY details.ordid;
```

But I am getting this error:

```
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  The error seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `select` columns don't match the `group by` -- you have two unaggregated columns in the `select` and only one in the `group by`.  Presumably, you want either:

```
select o.adate, d.ordid, sum(d.price) as total 
from details d join
     order o
     on d.ordid = o.ordid 
group by o.adate, d.ordid;
```

Or more likely:

```
select o.adate, sum(d.price) as total 
from details d join
     order o
     on d.ordid = o.ordid 
group by o.adate;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.
- `order` is a really bad name for a table because it is a SQL keyword.